# Finding the sum of sales when a series of conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that looks like below. It contains a key (id) that identified each transaction. Within each transaction, there may be multiple items that were purchased, thus someome with transact 103 has three different id values because they purchased three different items.

Here is what I am trying to do. For a given set of conditions, I want to total number of items that were purchased (item qty). Let's say that my conditions are that for stores 20 and 35, AND items 7, 12, aned 21, I want to find the total number of purchased items (item qty). When condition x is met, which is the reason for the subquery, sun up the item quantity to get total sales.

Can anyone help?

```
transac id  item_qty   store      item
101     1            2             20         13
102     2            1             35         21
103     3            3             35         16 
103     4            1             35          12
103     5            1             35          7 
104     6            1             15          21
104     7            2              20         7
```

I have the following query which is related to my example but when I utilize such queries on my data it returns a null value each time.

```
SELECT SUM(Cnt) AS "Sales Count"
FROM (SELECT ti.id, SUM(ti.item_qty) AS Cnt
            FROM dbo.vTransactions1 ti
        WHERE ti.store IN (20, 35)
        AND ti.item IN (7, 12, 21)
        GROUP BY ti.id) inner_query1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to `group by store and item` and then calculating the sum. This way you would be able to add more conditions if required based on valid combinations of (Store,Item). You have grouped by `id` which is not worth as each row will have unique id so no group will be formed.

For given condition you can write as;

```
;with CTE as
( 
  select sum(item_qty) as Cnt,store,item
  from test 
  group by store,item
) 
select sum (Cnt) as [Sales Count]
from CTE
where store in (20,35)
and item in (7,12,21))
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b62c2f/8)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why there is a subquery here.  Unless I'm missing something, this should work:

```
select sum (item_qty)
FROM dbo.vTransactions1 ti
    WHERE ti.store IN (20, 35)
    AND ti.item IN (7, 12, 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add extra conditions in the outer query - you either need to

1. remove the "Sum" from Sum(Cnt) as the Sum is already done in the sub query (and probably return the ID as well); OR
2. You need to add GROUP BY condition to the outer query as well.